# VBA assignment causing program to crash but only in presentation view

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to debug a User form for Powerpoint. It all seems to be working perfectly when I run it directly using the run button in the editor. However when I try to run it from a presentation mode using a button fixed in the masterslide the program seems to crash suddenly. 
The form will run and when I press ok the first message box I used for debugging will show and then nothing.

Here is the code

```
    Private Sub OKBut_Click()
' Message Box Working
MsgBox ("OkBut running")
Dim oSlide As Slide

Dim lCurrentView As Long

      ' Get the current view type.
lCurrentView = ActiveWindow.ViewType
'These message boxes do not appear
MsgBox ("Test")
MsgBox (CStr(lCurrentView))
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Are they maybe shown behind the presentation, that is full screen and "grabs" the screen? Try Alt+Tab.

Comment: I'm not experienced with powerpoint-vba, but concluding from similar behaviour in excel, I'd guess this is caused by unallowed interactions with your UI (powerpoint slide). For example, in Excel you can't use a user function to execute vba code that alters cell contents and similar stuff. So, running the form from a slide and altering that slide through this form may be prohibited. Hence, it's not working. Keep in mind: this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveWindow.ViewType is only applicable in design mode. When you are running a slide show there are no active windows and it will throw an error thats why you are not hitting the message box calls.

Answer (score 0):

Are you unloading the form at the end of the OKbut sub with this?

```
Unload Me
```

Don't hide it as this will definitely cause problems.

You may also find the user experience will be a lot better if you use a shape rather than an ActiveX control on the slide to trigger the form. Microsoft will show lots of verbose security messages when you use ActiveX controls on slides/masters/layouts and may even block the content.

Add a sub in a standard module and assign it to a shape on your master:

```
Sub ShowMyForm(ClickedShape as Shape)
  frmMyForm.Show
End Sub
```

Finally, this will error during a slide show:

```
lCurrentView = ActiveWindow.ViewType
```

You can address slide show windows in slide show mode with this:

```
Application.SlideShowWindows(1)
```

If you're looking for the slide index during a slide show, user this:

```
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex
```